# Which measuring unit is used in SCNVector3 position for x, y and z in ARKit

Tags: swift, arkit

let position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -2)
what is the distance in measuring units from the origin to the above point

Comment: matrix_float4x4 Maybe this one Help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45216780/10150796

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `ARKit` the unit of measurement is in `Meters`.

[image]

When you launch your `ARKit` app, the worldOrigin is set at `SCNVector3Zero` which is (0,0,0) (or in the diagram where the X,Y,Z axis intersect):

> ARKit defines a world coordinate space for you to use to place virtual
>   content and locate detected objects in an AR experience. By default,
>   this space is based on the initial position and orientation of the
>   device when the session begins.

An `SCNVector3` is simply:

> a three-component vector which is used for a variety of purposes, such
>   as describing node or vertex positions, surface normals, and scale or
>   translation transforms. The different vector components should be
>   interpreted based on the context in which the vector is being used.

So each part corresponds to the X, Y and Z values e.g:

```
let position = SCNVector3 (x, y, z)
```

Given your `position var` you are saying that you want to place the object centrally in regard to the `worldOrigin` and 2meters away from the camera.

Hope it helps...