# ARKit - Official source for unit of measuring?

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760421/which-measuring-unit-is-used-in-scnvector3-position-for-x-y-and-z-in-arkit?newreg=ac23b7d4be634535a1bb9734259435da), ARKit uses meters for measuring.

Is there any official source for this, somewhere within Apple's Documentation, for example? I've been searching for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SceneKit’s world space corresponds to the ***`meter`*** defined in the [International System of Units](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenesource/unit_dictionary_keys).

The same units are set for ARKit space and RealityKit space.

Watch [ARKit WWDC 2017 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/602/) (time: 14:32).

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!