# How can I get the yaw, pitch, roll of an ARAnchor in absolute terms?

Tags: swift, arkit

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now.

Given an ARKit-based app where I track a user's face, how can I get the face's rotation in absolute terms, from its anchor?

I can get the transform of the ARAnchor, which is a simd_matrix4x4.
There's a lot of info on how to get the position out of that matrix (it's the 3rd column), but nothing on the rotation!

I want to be able to control a 3D object outside of the app, by passing YAW, PITCH and ROLL.

The latest I thing I tried actually works somewhat:

```
let arFrame = session.currentFrame!
guard let faceAnchor = arFrame.anchors[0] as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }

let faceMatrix = SCNMatrix4.init(faceAnchor.transform)
let node = SCNNode()

node.transform = faceMatrix
let rotation = node.worldOrientation
```

rotation.x .y and .z have values I could use, **but as I move my phone the values change**. For instance, if I turn 180˚ and keep looking at the phone, the values change wildly based on the position of the phone.

I tried changing the world alignment in the ARConfiguration, but that didn't make a difference.

Am I reading the wrong parameters? This should have been a lot easier!

Comment: You need to calculate the eulerAngle for pitch, yaw and roll. There's near no documentation about it, but give a look [here](https://michael-martinez.fr/arkit-transform-matrices-quaternions-and-related-conversions/)

Comment: While that does give me the values, they're still not "absolute". Meaning, if I rotate myself and the phone (spin on a chair while looking straight at the phone for instance), the rotation values change drastically.

Comment: Did you try to convert the coordinates into another coordinate system with node.convert ?

Comment: Yes. I tried to do node.transform = node.convertTransform(node.transform, from: sceneView.scene.rootNode) but it was still affected by camera movements. Did I do it wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured it out...

Once you have the face anchor, some calculations need to happen with its transform matrix, and the camera's transform.

Like this:

```
let arFrame = session.currentFrame!
guard let faceAnchor = arFrame.anchors[0] as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }

let projectionMatrix = arFrame.camera.projectionMatrix(for: .portrait, viewportSize: self.sceneView.bounds.size, zNear: 0.001, zFar: 1000)
let viewMatrix = arFrame.camera.viewMatrix(for: .portrait)

let projectionViewMatrix = simd_mul(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix)
let modelMatrix = faceAnchor.transform
let mvpMatrix = simd_mul(projectionViewMatrix, modelMatrix)

// This allows me to just get a .x .y .z rotation from the matrix, without having to do crazy calculations
let newFaceMatrix = SCNMatrix4.init(mvpMatrix)
let faceNode = SCNNode()
faceNode.transform = newFaceMatrix
let rotation = vector_float3(faceNode.worldOrientation.x, faceNode.worldOrientation.y, faceNode.worldOrientation.z)
```

rotation.x .y and .z will return the face's pitch, yaw, roll (respectively)

I'm adding a small multiplier and inverting 2 of the axis, so it ends up like this:

```
yaw = -rotation.y*3
pitch = -rotation.x*3
roll = rotation.z*1.5
```

Phew!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are using front camera and `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`, which is not supposed to give you absolute values. I would try to configure second `ARSession` for back camera with `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` which does provide absolute values. The final solution will probably require values from both `ARSession`'s. I haven't tested this hypothesis yet but it seems to be the only way.

**UPDATE** quote from [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration) -

> The ARWorldTrackingConfiguration class tracks the device's movement with six degrees of freedom (6DOF): specifically, the three rotation axes (roll, pitch, and yaw), and three translation axes (movement in x, y, and z). This kind of tracking can create immersive AR experiences: A virtual object can appear to stay in the same place relative to the real world, even as the user tilts the device to look above or below the object, or moves the device around to see the object's sides and back.

Apparently, other tracking configurations do **not** have this ability.

Comment: That seems like a crazy solution! Knowing the ARFrame / camera position, ARKit should be able to return the absolute rotation of the face anchor without factoring in the device's rotation itself :x

Comment: "The ARWorldTrackingConfiguration class tracks the device's movement with six degrees of freedom (6DOF): specifically, the three rotation axes (roll, pitch, and yaw), and three translation axes (movement in x, y, and z).

This kind of tracking can create immersive AR experiences: A virtual object can appear to stay in the same place relative to the real world, even as the user tilts the device to look above or below the object, or moves the device around to see the object's sides and back." - other configurations do *not* have this ability.

Comment: While what you're saying is true, in the ARFaceAnchor documentation, Apple says: "The inherited transform property describes the face’s current position and orientation in world coordinates; that is, in a coordinate space relative to that specified by the worldAlignment property of the session configuration."
However, I've tried all 3 worldAlignment properties and I can't get the transform to ignore the face transform of the device itself

Comment: BTW `Using gravity and heading alignment requires tracking the device's geographic location. Your app's Info.plist must include user-facing text for the NSLocationUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key so that the user can grant your app permission for location tracking.` - is your `Info.plist` correct and permission granted?

Comment: It's alright. I've answered my own question with the solution. Thanks